# RelativeLayout expanding but not shrinking

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` that is being expanded on click by setting a `LinearLayout` inside to `View.VISIBLE`. This works fine, but as soon as I set the LinearLayout inside to INVISIBLE, the LL hides but the parent RelativeLayout stays at it's size.

Do I really have to store the LayoutParams before expanding for later restore, or is there some built-in magic to auto shrink the size as it's working for growing?

---

**list_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandArea"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**ListAdapter.java**

```
// shrinking does not work when:
v.findViewById(R.id.expandArea).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// whereas expanding works correct:
v.findViewById(R.id.expandArea).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: use `View.GONE` instead of `view.INVISIBLE`

Comment: Use Visibility.GONE to hide view. Because INVISIBLE means the view will be there but not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **GONE** instead of **INVISIBLE**

```
v.findViewById(R.id.expandArea).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```